# How do i subtract discount text box from total text box more than one time?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the total textbox and discount textbox , I need to subtract the discount from total value , the issue how i will save the total value in variable and subtract the discount from the total if i entered the discount more than one time for example :

total value = 500  and discount = 100 then total = 500 - 100 = 400 . 
The case i need to solve it suppose i need to add more discount or change the discount value from 100 to 200 how i will program it to subtract 500 - 200 = 300 
and not 400 - 200 = 200 .

I tried the following code textbox key

```
private void txtdiscount_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(textOrderTotal.Text);
            decimal discount = Convert.ToDecimal(txtdiscount.Text);

            if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Return))
            {
                total = Convert.ToDecimal(textOrderTotal.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(txtdiscount.Text);
                textOrderTotal.Text = total.ToString();
            }
        }
```

How can i subtract discount from total more than one time subtract from grand total , also how to prevent discount value = or greater than total value ?

Comment: That looks a lot like windows forms code, but the question is tagged as asp.net?

Comment: Anyway, the answer is probably to not change the original total, rather have another variable that stores the value of the original total less any discounts applied.

Comment: @stuartd yes it is windows forms application , can you please tell me how to keep the original total in case the discount value changed more than one time thank you ?

Comment: You need three fields, not two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the Original Total. If you have a button which calculates the `Total`, you could use

```
private decimal _originalTotal = 0;
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _originalTotal = decimal.Parse(textOrderTotal.Text);
}
```

Or if the `Total` itself is being manually entered,

```
private decimal _originalTotal = 0;
private void textOrderTotal_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Return || e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
  {
    _originalTotal = decimal.Parse(textOrderTotal.Text);
  }
}
```

The idea is to capture the original total, before the discount is being applied. Now, you could apply the discount as

```
private void txtdiscount_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  decimal total = _originalTotal;
  decimal discount = Convert.ToDecimal(txtdiscount.Text);

  if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Return))
  {
    total = _originalTotal - discount;
    textOrderTotal.Text = total.ToString();
  }
}
```

Please note you need to do the calculation based on previous captured `Original Total`. Also note following code in OP

```
total = Convert.ToDecimal(textOrderTotal.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(txtdiscount.Text);
```

You had already converted the `Text` in the two text boxes to decimal in first two lines in the method. You could reuse them instead of converting again. In this particular, we would use the captured original total instead.

```
 total = _originalTotal - discount;
```